# Parallel Aggregates in Scala using associative operators

Tags: scala

I want to perform aggregate of a list of values in Scala. Here are few considerations:

- aggregate function [1] is associative as well as commutative: examples are plus and multiply
- this function is applied to the list in parallel so as to utilize all the cores of CPU

Here is an implementation:

```
package com.example.reactive

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object AggregateParallel {

  private def pm[T](l: List[Future[T]])(zero: T)(fn: (T, T) => T): Future[T] = {

    val l1 = l.grouped(2)
    val l2 = l1.map { sl =>
      sl match {
        case x :: Nil => x
        case x :: y :: Nil =>
          for (a <- x; b <- y) yield fn(a, b)
        case _ => Future(zero)
      }
    }.toList

    l2 match {
      case x :: Nil => x
      case x :: xs => pm(l2)(zero)(fn)
      case Nil => Future(zero)
    }
  }

  def parallelAggregate[T](l: List[T])(zero: T)(fn: (T, T) => T): T = {
    val n = pm(l.map(Future(_)))(zero)(fn)
    Await.result(n, 1000 millis)
    n.value.get.get
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    // multiply empty list: zero value is 1
    println(parallelAggregate(List[Int]())(1)((x, y) => x * y))

    // multiply a list: zero value is 1
    println(parallelAggregate(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))(1)((x, y) => x * y))

    // sum a list: zero value is 0
    println(parallelAggregate(List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))(0)((x, y) => x + y))

    // sum a list: zero value is 0
    val bigList1 = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).map(BigInt(_))
    println(parallelAggregate(bigList1)(0)((x, y) => x + y))

    // sum a list of BigInt: zero value is 0
    val bigList2 = (1 to 100).map(BigInt(_)).toList
    println(parallelAggregate(bigList2)(0)((x, y) => x + y))

    // multiply a list of BigInt: zero value is 1
    val bigList3 = (1 to 100).map(BigInt(_)).toList
    println(parallelAggregate(bigList3)(1)((x, y) => x * y))
  }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
1
120
15
15
5050
93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
```

How else can I achieve the same objective or improve this code in Scala?

*EDIT1*:

I have implemented bottom up aggregate. I think I am quite close to the `aggregate` method in Scala ( below). The difference being that I am only splitting into sub lists of two elements:

Scala implementation:

```
def aggregate[S](z: S)(seqop: (S, T) => S, combop: (S, S) => S): S = {
  executeAndWaitResult(new Aggregate(z, seqop, combop, splitter))
}
```

With this implementation I assume that the aggregate happens in parallel like so:

```
List(1,2,3,4,5,6)
-> split parallel -> List(List(1,2), List(3,4), List(5,6) )
-> execute in parallel -> List( 3, 7, 11 )
-> split parallel -> List(List(3,7), List(11) )
-> execute in parallel -> List( 10, 11)
-> Result is 21
```

Is that correct to assume that Scala `aggregate` is also doing bottom-up aggregates in parallel?

[1] http://www.mathsisfun.com/associative-commutative-distributive.html

Comment: The parallel list of scala already have an `aggregate` method that do you just what you're asking for. http://markusjais.com/scalas-parallel-collections-and-the-aggregate-method/

Comment: Please check my EDIT1 in the question.

Comment: I answered your edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parallel lists of scala already have an `aggregate` method that do you just what you're asking for:
http://markusjais.com/scalas-parallel-collections-and-the-aggregate-method/

It works like `foldLeft` but takes an extra parameter:

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) ⇒ B): B 
def aggregate[B](z: ⇒ B)(seqop: (B, A) ⇒ B, combop: (B, B) ⇒ B): B
```

When called on a parallel collection `aggregate` splits the collection in N parts, uses `foldLeft` parrallely on each parts, and uses `combop` to unit all the results.

But when called on a non parallel collection `aggregate` just works like `foldLeft` and ignores the `combop`.

To have consistent results you need associative and commutative operators because you don't control how the list will be split at all.

A short example:

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).par.aggregate(1)(_ * _, _ * _)
   res0: Int = 120
```

Answer to Edit1 (improved according to comment):

I don't think it's the right approach, for a N items list you'll create N `Future`s. Which creates a big overhead in scheduling. Unless the `seqop` is really long, I'll avoid creating a `Future` each time you are calling it.

Comment: Creating a Future doesn't mean creating a thread. It is upto the scheduler ( via ExecutionContext ) to control how many number of threads to schedule the futures on. As you mentioned there is no way to control the splits, so Scala's `aggregate` is somewhat limiting IMHO. What are the alternatives other than standard Scala library ?

Comment: @tuxdna yes, Future and Thread are different but by creating too many Future you give more work to the Scheduler and therefore slow down your code. IMHO Future should be created only for long computation. In your example summing two integers is certainly not worse a Future.

Comment: @tuxdna As for other alternative I don't know. The scala collection library was designed so you don't have to worry about how you're splitting your computation when parallelizing. Why would you want more control over this ?

Comment: @gozu: I would want to apply aggregate on a list of of values. These values could be big integers or some other thing. So the aggregate function may be actually much slower that simple integer multiplication. Thats why the aggregate function is applied inside a `Future`.